# Configure TypeScript to infer generic from special function name in same file

Tags: typescript

I'd like to reduce repetition / boilerplate in common code patterns in a project by configuring TypeScript to do something kind of magical - infer a generic based on the presence of a function with a special name.

Imagine I'm using a framework which provides a `getStuff` function with this interface

```
function getStuff<T> (): T {}
```

Note that `getStuff()` takes no arguments, so why/how can it have a generic? Well, in the framework, due to frameworky magic, it will actually return the value of another function `loadStuff` that is defined in the same file.

```
function loadStuff () {
  return { a: 1, b: 2 }
}

function something () {
  const stuff = getStuff()

  if (stuff.a === 1) ... // true
}
```

Trouble is, TypeScript of course knows nothing about this framework magic, hence the generic provided by the framework.

To get typing on `stuff` I have to give it the manual hint using the generic on `getStuff`.

```
const stuff = getStuff<{ a: number, b: number }>()

if (stuff.a === 'hello') ... // great, now I get autocomplete on .a and a type error
```

What I'd like to achieve is using a global config to not have to give this manual hint to `getStuff` every time.

In plain language, what I want to tell TypeScript is, globally within this project, when I use `getStuff<T>`, autofill `<T>` with the return type of a function at the top scope of the same file (module) called `loadStuff`.

I am fine with having these special names for `loadStuff` and `getStuff` that I must use exactly.

I know I could achieve this with code generation, but I'd really prefer to avoid that if possible. I'd love it if TypeScript could be 'magically' configured to do it dynamically and globally for the project. Is this possible?

Comment: (Huh, I don't get the close vote. The question seems clear to me.)

Comment: What framework is it? Do they not provide a solution to this? Seems odd to make you supply the generic each time...

Comment: remix inspired the question in this instance (loader and useLoader), but I've wondered it for other frameworks / libraries too, including my own react-frontload. It's a pattern I've seen come up particularly with react hooks - ie a framework provided hook that TS cannot 'link' to some other framework provided function.

Answer (score 2):

I'm 99% sure you can't do exactly what you've said you want (but I'll be interested to be proven wrong), so here's an alternative:

You can do this once per file:

```typescript
const getThisStuff: () => ReturnType<typeof loadStuff> = getStuff;
```

Then each usage is just:

```
const stuff = getThisStuff();
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAcwKZQMpRMYAeAFQD5EAKASgC5EDEBvAWAChFXEAndEdpMEAG36IAhgGdE4ANZg4AdyRiaAbmYBfZs1CRYCRPzjCAJlhzAy5eszYcuPeiOoBGADSIARtQBMidU1-MIBFEoFHQCAAsYURNcagpEAF4SACVbMAIATwAHVDwobNQ4M30jGOASBNDMbFwVJk1waHgkUTgAW3RIsGRzSxY2QLBgxGDTRKqIqLKKDX7WGDNSUdwAOmFEhMrHCzpEAHo9xAB1OHZJUVnrX1UgA)

This may be what you mean by "code generation," but in case it isn't...

Comment: this is what I meant by code generation, yeah - and is the pattern I'd go for if I were to go that route. This could be by hand (though it's still at least a little repetitive having to do this per file, but could be copy pasteable) or by literal code generation with a keyboard shortcut or similar. I have also seen this kind of pattern being used in various libraries (usually with a global singleton you set up whose only purpose is to set up the correct types) and conclude that since it's such a common problem, it's very likely the case that TS can't solve it (yet) with any special config.

Comment: @davnicwil - It's surprising to me they don't use [something like this](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-hcjrtd?file=App.tsx) instead, but I haven't been into it in any depth. Would make the type stuff much more straightforward and remove magic (I'm not a fan of magic in development, just in entertainment :-) ). Not knowing Remix, I don't know whether it would be possible for you to put that kind of wrapper in place (obviously not necessarily exactly *that* wrapper). FWIW.